# Logback date-based file rolling doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, logging, logback

I use Logback 1.0.10 and I'm trying to get log file rolling to work, but no matter what I do, whenever a new day comes, it just truncates the log file.

Any ideas?  I use Java 6 and this is for a webapp running in Tomcat 6 on a Windows 2008 server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">

    <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>${log.dir}/${log.name}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${log.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="${log.level}" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Try removing the `.log` in `FileNamePattern` tag.

Comment: @Anubhab: But looking at the [examples](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy), it should not be necessary :/

Comment: Also from the examples i saw `%d` will take default daily rolling..So you can ommit explicit mention for that :)

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing... I realize now that I forgot `${log.dir}` in `FileNamePattern` and ta-da, the old log file was in the parent dir.

Comment: LOL...now you can answer  yourself and close it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize now that I forgot `${log.dir}` in `FileNamePattern` and ta-da, the old log file was in the parent directory.